# Set local ENV variable in Windows command from Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, command-line, rake, environment-variables

I've made a Rake task for local dev that will build the project, start watching it for auto-compilation, and also start up a Thin server to see the compiled app.

I implemented Foreman to allow for setting up local ENV variables, which the project is now depending on. It works great - except it needs to also work on Windows.

My solution was to parse the .env files and manually set the vars in I start the server, ala:

```
$ MY_ENV_VAR=12345 ruby -rubygems app.rb
```

It works great when I execute it myself by hand. But if I try to execute that command via my Rake task - `sh %{MY_ENV_VAR=12345 ruby -rubygems app.rb}`, it fails:

```
Command failed with status (127): [MY_ENV_VAR=12345 ruby -rubygems app.rb...]
```

I've tried executing it with `sh %{}`, `exec`, `system`, `%x{}`, and backticks with no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`Kernel#system` with the `env` argument](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-system):

```ruby
env = {'FOO' => '123'}
cmd = 'echo $FOO'
system(env, cmd) # => prints "123", returns true
```

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts!